# cx_Freeze python 3.4 unable to install (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am running Windows 10 64-bit. I tried getting cx_freeze for Python 3.4 (which I have installed) but the moment i tell it to **Install** it stops responding and windows closes the installer. I have looked for a solution through and through but I can't find a similar question, let alone an answer. It seems I am the only one having this problem.

I have also tried using the command prompt to install cx_Freeze using this command:

```
py -3.4 -m pip install cx_Freeze
```

It says that

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\cx_Freeze'
```

Comment: Has this happened to any other package or just cx_Freeze?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. What worked for me was installing a python package (WinPython), where the most important things are preinstalled (pandas, numpy, scipy etc. AND cx_freeze). It's an easy way to get python running and having a good IDE (Spyder).

Visit: http://winpython.github.io/#releases